# c# SQL Can't read 0000-00-00 00:00:00 timestamp

Tags: c#, mysql, sockets, tcp, mariadb

my develop environment is next :
windows 2012
ms vc 2010 (c#)
WIndows Form + Console
using DB tool is HeidiSQL
Developing Program is Async TCP Socket Server(game server)
DB is MariaDB

CreateCode is Next:

```
CREATE TABLE `use_users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `passwd` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `role` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `iconpath` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `enabled` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `logged` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `uploaddate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COMMENT='USER DATABASE'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=103
;
```

and query **select * from use_users;** work fine at HeidiSQL Client
(And my c++ test tcp server with boost::asio working fine *- using mysql_fetch_row* is work fine too )

but only c# server cannot read row that TIMESTAMP is **0000-00-00 00:00:00**
my query code is next

```
        void launchQueryWithPooled(string query)
        {
            _succeeded = true;
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
            using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                try
                {   
                    IAsyncResult asResult = da.FillAsync(Result);
                    while (!asResult.IsCompleted);
                    Util.Log("Query Finished");
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    _succeeded = false;
                    Util.Log("ERROR : Query("+query+") : "+ ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

when i query **select name from use_users;** it works fine
when i query **select lastlogin from use_users where `id` = 0** it works fine (id 0's lastlogin is  current time value)
when i query **select lastlogin from use_users where `id` = 1** (id 1's lastlogin is 0000-00-00 00:00:00) it returns **no result**
and every select query that's result includes TIMESTAMP 0000-00-00 00:00:00 returns **no result** (however it has a vaild timestamp or other valid result, it changed to **no result**)

i tried MySqlCommand but the result is same
i don't know how it happens and how can select 0000-00-00 00:00:00 normaly
please someone help me!

Comment: Can you test it with the timestamp `0001-01-01 00:00:00` ? This is  the [DateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so maby C# just can't parse `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: i finded similar clue. but i can't try. when i tried this query `update use_users set date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00' where date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';` but 0001-01-01 is error with message 'SQL Error (1292): Incorrect datetime value: '0001-01-01 00:00:00' for column 'date' at row 2' may [DateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is error in mariadb or mysql

Comment: The Timestamp minvalue of mariadb is  '1970-01-01 00:00:01' as shown in the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/data-types/date-and-time-data-types/timestamp/). `0000-00-00` is just the representation for 0.

Comment: I suggest making the column nullable, so the default value is null. This would be even better, because never logging in means NO timestamp and not the timestamp `0000-00-00`.

Comment: thank you! and i digging in this problem and finally find a answer : simply add **allowzerodatetime=true** to MySql Connection String.  it works fine. but i don't know why it returns NO RESULT even it has other vaild TIMESTAMP results. (i guess a exception occur and catch it inside of C# Mysql Library...)